# Technique to select a row or multiple rows of a table, and give that element a background

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I am making a game level editor where i created a grid using tables. Now first of all i implemented the click and drag feature to select multiple cells at a time.

Now i need to change the background of that cell which are selected by clicking another element or button below the table.

Also, i need to create a multidimensional array from this grid to know which cell has an element on it.
Any help?.
https://jsfiddle.net/56e7h23L/1/

```
var row = 15;
var column = 30;
var table = document.createElement('table');
var mousedown = false;
var selected = false;
for(i = 1; i <= row; i++){
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for(j = 1; j <=column; j++){
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.className = 'cell';

    td.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault(); 
    });

    td.onmousedown = (function(i, j){
      return function(){
        console.log(i);
        console.log(j);
        if(selected != true){
          this.className += ' active';
          mousedown = true;
        }else{
          this.className = 'cell';
        }
      }
    })(i, j);

    td.onmouseover = (function(i,j){
        return function(){
          if(mousedown){
            this.className += ' active';
          }  
        }
    })(i, j);


    document.onmouseup = function(){
      console.log('hello');
      mousedown = false;
    }

    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Would be much easier if u used JQuery :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the td of the previous and next (from current) tr by doing

```
td.onmousedown = function(){

   var currentIndexInParent = whichChild(this);
   var tdAtSameLevelAboveTr = this.parentElement.previousSibling.childNodes.item( currentIndexInParent );
   var tdAtSameLevelBelowTr = this.parentElement.nextSibling.childNodes.item( currentIndexInParent );
};

function whichChild(elem){
    var  i= 0;
    while((elem=elem.previousSibling)!=null) ++i;
    return i;
}
```